# Remove Unused Data Range-Libre Office Calc (Line Chart)

Tags: libreoffice, graph

I'm creating a line chart with Libre Office Calc. All of the number values stay within a high range, so when I create the chart, there is a large gap of unused data on the bottom of the chart, and its squashing the actual data down. I want the lowest value in the chart to be at the bottom, and the highest value in the chart to be at the top. How can I remove extra values from the view, so I can only see the data's range? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: LO Calc does roughly what you want by default.  e.g. I just created a sheet with a column containing values from 198..222 in steps of 2, and made a line chart from it.  The chart displayed the range from 185 to 225. The only way I could make it display from 0 on the Y axis was by explicitly adding a `0` value to the column (and that was extremely obvious in the line chart) - an empty cell alone wouldn't do it.   I can only suggest that you right-click on the chart and examine the `Data Ranges...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the data's range you can do the following steps:

0. There is a chart.
   [image: LibreOffice Calc]
1. To switch to the chart editing mode, double-click on the chart. We get the following picture:
   [image: LibreOffice Calc]
2. By arrow 1, select the Y-axis. After that, follow the arrow 2, go to the axis settings.
   [image: LibreOffice Calc]
3. In the window that opens, the boundaries we need.
   [image: Options window]
4. Congratulations, now the graph is visible from where we want
   [image: Final result]

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried it out and it worked perfectly!